# Is there a working example of simple Net::OpenID::Consumer::Lite CGI script?

Tags: perl, openid, cgi

I have seen the examples of [Net::OpenID::Consumer::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-OpenID-Consumer-Lite) on CPAN but I was hoping to get a single script that uses POST method. If nobody has this than I will post my solution back here once I get it working.

Comment: I say post what you have now and replace it as you get parts working. People acn help you along the way. :)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the only applicable test in the manifest and it doesn't seem too useful 
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TOKUHIROM/Net-OpenID-Consumer-Lite-0.02/xt/001_mixi.t [`Apache2::AuthMixi` also uses it a bit](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#77rSAzngy-E/lib/Apache2/AuthMixi.pm&q=net::openid::consumer::lite&sa=N&cd=5&ct=rc)

This module simply delegates to `LWP::UserAgent`. I don't like it, it should subclass LWP::UserAgent instead of delegating. You can find the docs for `LWP::UserAgent` on cpan, and access the base copy through the hidden method `_ua` (though, by convention, the preceding underscore tells you it isn't supported and it is supposed to be kept secret)

```
my $csr = Net::OpenID::Consumer::Lite->new();
$csr->_ua->post(); # same as LWP::UserAgent::post()
```

It seems as if you're supposed to use only `handle_server_response()` which calls `_check_authentication()` which calls `_get()` which delegates to `->_ua->get()`.

check_authentication() wants an HashRef jump-table with 5 events for `not_openid`, `setup_required`, `cancelled`, `verified`, and `error`. In addition I believe it wants a bunch of key (`openid.`) prefixed stuff, and values.

Per the code, for a request to be sent `$request->{'openid.mode'}` must exist in the `$request` and be set (preferably to) `check_authentication`, and not set to 'cancel'. The `openid.user_setup_url` key must logically not be set or it will just call the respective callback. It must also have an `op_endpoint.endpoint` key set, which is where the request is destined to go.

This code isn't hard to read, [I'd suggesting taking a look](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TOKUHIROM/Net-OpenID-Consumer-Lite-0.02/lib/Net/OpenID/Consumer/Lite.pm) The [author also seems to have a bunch of modules](http://search.cpan.org/~tokuhirom/) which is a good sign. I don't like jump-tables with data like that, it seems kind of weird from a UI perspective.